# SQL - Find greatest count

Tags: sql

Just a quick SQL question. I've been working on a problem that looks to find the sailor with the most red boats reserved. The schema looks like this:

[image]

I know that for each individual red boat, you can find the number of sailors who have reserved it with

```
SELECT B.bid, COUNT (*) AS sailorcount 

FROM Boats B, Reserves R

WHERE R.bid = B.bid AND B.color = ‘red’

GROUP BY B.bid
```

So now I'm trying to figure out how I can figure out which sailor has reserved the most red boats. Thanks for any insight anyone may have!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join all the tables together. Here, because `Boats` is joined on it's unique PK, it does not duplicate any rows from previous joins, it only limits the existing rows. So a straight `COUNT(*)` works

Don't use the `,` joining syntax, it has been deprecated for many years already.

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)    -- for SQL Server, Sybase
    S.sid, S.sname, COUNT(*) AS RedBoats
FROM Sailors S
JOIN Reserves R ON R.sid = S.sid
JOIN Boats B ON R.bid = B.bid AND B.color = 'red'
GROUP BY S.sid, S.sname
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
-- LIMIT 1    -- for MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Math guy here, so I'm just dipping into SQL. I'm just using straight SQL, so would this only hold for MySQL, Postgres, etc.?

Comment: What does "straight SQL" mean? Any SQL variant which allows you to limit rows can do it with one of these syntaxes. This covers you nearly all major DBMS on the market

Comment: Sorry, just plain vanilla SQL, so I believe the SELECT TOP (1) should work. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: There is no such thing as "plain vanilla SQL", which provider are you using? Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server.